# I can't import the js library script p5.js CDN error

Tags: cdn, p5.js

```sh
Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.4/lib/p5.min.js". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not
explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I got this error while trying to make some chrome extension right now. I try to use p5.js library. But I still got this error several time. What is the death over here! Could you help me, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the p5.js CDN service is not working well right now I install it manually. And then it works.

[https://p5js.org/getstarted/#:~:text=Downloading%20a%20copy%20of%20the%20p5.js%20library](https://p5js.org/getstarted/#:%7E:text=Downloading%20a%20copy%20of%20the%20p5.js%20library)